# Localization in Swift / Kurdish

Tags: swift, xcode, localization

I am currently building an app in three languages English, Arabic, and Kurdish. I have already managed to do the English and Arabic but there is no choice for Kurdish. Is there any way to add my language (Kurdish) to my app in Xcode ( I am using Swift)?

Answer (score 3):

### Kurdish language code: `ku`

You can add this language in two ways

1. Create a folder with the required `Localizable` files and then drag them to the project

[image]

2. Selecting a language from the list of other languages

[image]

Comment: that was really helpful. I use Xcode 9 and for some reason I can not find Kurdish in other languages. Is there anything I can do about that ?

Comment: If you still can not find this language, then you have to use the first way. It always works

Answer (score 1):

Close XCode.
Open project file (yourProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj) in a text editor and find

```
knownRegions = (
```

You can see other languages; so, you can add your language code to the end of values:

```
knownRegions = (
                en,
                Base,
                tr,
                ckb
            );
```

Save and open Xcode again, you can find your lang in localization list. Don't forget to enable for files that you need.

[image: your lang in localization xcode screenshot]

PS: ***ckb*** is the language code for Central Kurdish (Sorani)